# Using a custom insertion operator with Google Test throws "invalid operands to binary expression" compilation error

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, clang, googletest, argument-dependent-lookup

Compiling this code with `clang-3.6`

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& v)
{
  for (const auto &it : v)
    os << it << " ";
  return os;
}

TEST(Case, Test)
{
  bool foo{false};
  std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};

  EXPECT_TRUE(foo) << v;
}
```

produces the error

```
gtest/include/gtest/gtest-message.h:131:10: error: invalid operands to binary expression
      ('std::basic_stringstream<char>' and 'const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >')
    *ss_ << val;
    ~~~~ ^  ~~~
```

If I use the operator with ostream objects there is no error, so I believe the problem lies in the EXPECT_TRUE macro. All related Google Test macros appear to produce this error. The code compiles, runs and produces the correct output with `g++`.

I believe argument-dependent lookup is failing to find `operator<<` but I don't know how to help it out.

Using a non-existent `operator<<` with `std::cout` produces a similar error

```
test.cpp:23:13: error: invalid operands to binary expression 
      ('ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'std::vector<int>')
  std::cout << v;
  ~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~
```

but this time the `ostream` is not qualified with `std`, perhaps this allows the name lookup to succeed?

Comment: This is expected behavior. Your `operator<<` can't be found by ADL because it's not in the `std` namespace, and can't be found by normal unqualified lookup because the call occurred in the Google Test header, before the `operator<<` is declared.

Comment: Great, so this works if I move the declaration above the include, but I'm having trouble getting this to work in my actual code. I'm including my header which defines `operator<<` above `gtest.h`, but I suspect it's not working due to header guards. I can copy the declaration into my unit test file, or I can include `operator<<` in `gtest.h`, but these solutions aren't great. Is there a solution to this problem which doesn't involve putting the headers in a particular order?

Comment: Does something like http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d812cf16a8c1f34a work for you?

Comment: That looks good, if you submit it as an answer I'll accept it. I was hoping for some way to keep the original syntax but it doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Same issue here. Found this only on Clang but not GCC or MSVC. In my code I can move the include of 'gtest' after the include of my internal headers. This is not a clean solution, of course.